# Green's function in 2d from Brownian motion in the full space

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations

In dimension $d = 2$ the function $g(x) = - (2 \pi)^{-1} \log |x|$ is the Green's kernel associated to Laplace's equation. For example, if $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$ then the solution of $-\Delta u = f$ can be given by
$$ u(x) = \int g(x-y) f(y) dy $$

One also expects that the solution can be given by
$$ u(x) = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{E}_x[f(B_t)] dt $$
where under $\mathbb{P}_x$, the process $(B_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is a Brownian motion starting from $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$. But this doesn't work, and the integral can be seen to be diverging, thanks to the recurrence of the process. For example, consider $f \ge 0$.

Is there a way of fixing the argument so that we can represent the solution $u$ still in terms of a Brownian motion? I would expect the following might work, but I can't prove it:
$$ u(x) = \int_0^\infty \big( \mathbb{E}_x[f(B_t)] - \mathbb{E}_0[f(B_t)] \big) dt $$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4397134/949989).

Comment: Although, the solution of the resolvent equation (as per your link) is also diverging as you take the limit in $\lambda$, so it does not converge to the solution $u(x)$.

Comment: No one said that in 2d you can take the limit $\lambda\to 0\,.$